# Call Function php another page - Foreach

Tags: php, loops, foreach

look , i have create this code at php page called "func_selects.php".

```
<?php 
require('functions.php');
impressoras();
$result = impressoras();


function call(){
            
$imp_select = "";
foreach( $result as $imp){
$imp_select .= '<option value="'.$imp['nome'].'">'.$imp['nome'].'</option>';

} 
return $imp_select;

 }


 ?>
```

remember that result came from a another page called "functions.php" that run a PDO Query that return in array .

But for example , how u can see , my code above only create some options .

i wanna create a another page , for example called "index.php" where i'll execute that function.

for example

"f0.php"

```
<?php
 require('func_selects.php');
 call();
 $imp_select = call();

 ?>

<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
call();
</script>
<select name="kakaka" class="form-control"><option 
 value="2">sdsdsds</option><option value="talvez"><?php echo $imp_select ?>
 </option></select>
 </body>
</html>
```

but dont return nothing , someone could help me ?

Getting these errors

> Notice: Undefined variable: result in /var/www/tkclientespdo/func_selects.php on line 10
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/tkclientespdo/func_selects.php on line 10

Comment: so where did you include your functions.php file?

Comment: Have you defined `$result` somewhere before looping it? Enable error-reporting `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and check your logs.

Comment: i made some changes to undestand better.

Comment: can you share the value of $result ?

Comment: returned this with display_erros  : Notice: Undefined variable: result in /var/www/tkclientespdo/func_selects.php on line 10

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/tkclientespdo/func_selects.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined variable: result in /var/www/tkclientespdo/func_selects.php on line 10

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/tkclientespdo/func_selects.php on line 10

Comment: can you do a var_dump($result) ?

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() - this $imp['nome'] might not exist ... I still waiting to see what is $result, 3er time that I asked my code is working but I use plain html instead the foreach because you never show the content of $result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your `func_selects.php` as below.

```
<?php 
  require('functions.php');

  function call(){
    $result = impressoras();
    $imp_select = "";
    foreach( $result as $imp){
      $imp_select .= '<option value="'.$imp['nome'].'">'.$imp['nome'].'</option>';
    } 
    return $imp_select;
  }
?>
```